# python 3.8.5 win 10 : AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'loads'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

something wrong with my python,  I cant use josn (and other modules that uses it)

```
import json

print(dir(json))
# ['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']

sample_json = '{ "name":"John", "age":30}'
data = json.loads(sample_json)
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shay/PycharmProjects/General/test_01.py", line 9, in <module>
    data = json.loads(sample_json)
AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'loads'
```

I **don't** have another **json.py** file in py PC, I've checked it already.
what can I do?
I cant work.

Comment: It does look like `json` is referring to the wrong file, as I can't reproduce this. Having another file called `json.py` in the pwd *does* seem like the most likely explanation. That, or your Python installation got fubared somehow and that library file was emptied. Note, it would be *json.py*, not *python.py*.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `print(json.__file__)` print?

Comment: 1: you are right! I meant "json.py"       



    
2: it print: "None"